# How do you simplify areas of dense geometry?

Tags: modeling

In my model I have extremely high density of vertices/faces from using tools such as `dynamic topology`. However, I often find that some of these areas do not need such high detail and can be simplified.

Is there some sort of tool or addon which allows me to select the vertices and simplify them for me? I do not want to use remesh as that will remesh the entire model as opposed to just the desired area. I also can not use the decimate modifier either for the same reasons.

What is the best way to approach this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a simplify tool for this:

[image]

Set up proper detail size:

[image]

and paint these areas using this tool